# How can I import CDAP Pipeline other than the UI?

Tags: pipeline, cdap

Is there a way to import pipelines using CDAP CLI?
I am interested in automated pipeline deployment.

Comment: Just a simpl rest call. See here
https://docs.cask.co/cdap/5.1.2/en/reference-manual/http-restful-api/lifecycle.html#create-an-application

Answer (score 1):

You can import pipeline using CDAP REST API.

```
PUT /v3/namespaces/<namespace>/apps/<pipeline name>
```

The body of the request should be the pipeline JSON that you have exported.